# Crawling web to build a directory of a niche industry for SEO

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, directory-listing

I heard that some web sites crawl web to build a directory of companies in a niche domain. So, when people search for the name of the company they find that directory page.

I wonder if this is really effective? Isn't this considered as duplicate content since the presented information was collected from some web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only duplicate content if they republish the content they find. They're not doing that. They're creating a directory of sites in a niche which is original content.

Answer (score 0):

Usually sites like this are collecting info such as the company's address and other business info, and sometimes their ratings from sites such as Google Places. This is done with the intent on making it easy for customers to find and choose a company in that niche. This info is then presented in a different format on the new site.  This is seen as a directory and not as duplicate content.

If instead the scrapped blog entries from these various company's website to make the blog for their site, that would be seen as duplicate content since the scrapped articles would be the same.